# Bootstrap 3 form-horizontal with two-line label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I align vertically a label and an input when the label take two lines ?

Here is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="passwd_confirm">Confirmation du mot de passe:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwd_confirm" maxlength="32">
    </div>
  </div>
<form>
```

The default display is that the input and the first line of the label have the same baseline but I want to align the input with the vertical center of the label.

How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: is this bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap3, you could add a class to the parent that makes it a `flex` row, then use `align-items: center` to center vertically. You might also want to match the default `padding-top: 7px` value for the `.control-label` element by either removing that padding, or adding that to the right column/input as a padding or margin, depending on the rest of your layout.

```css
.form-group.valign {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .valign input {
    margin-top: 7px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group valign">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="passwd_confirm">Confirmation du mot<br> de passe:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwd_confirm" maxlength="32">
    </div>
  </div>
<form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael !! The flexbox works perfectly. I just replace the media query by this one: 
media (max-width: 768px) { 
  .form-group.valign {
 display: block; } }
to get the default behavior on small screens.